# Obtaining census block groups from shapefile based on latlong inputs - Java

Tags: java, coordinates, shapefile, coordinate-systems, census

I am new to `shapefile` processing. Kindly guide me on how to achieve my below query.

I am using this shapefile **tl_2018_us_aiannh.shp** from **census.gov : TIGER-LINE**. I am to obtain the *census block group* entities like *Block*, *Tract*, *County subdivision* and *County* details from the shapefile based on the *latitude and longitude* provided by the user.

My requirement is to achieve this by `shapefile` alone and not through any API's.

Can someone help on which framework I can achieve this?

**What I've tried/using so far**:

- I have used `GeoTools` to read the `shapefile` . Can I continue using the same? Will my requirement be achievable by this tool?
- I have gone through a documentation from **census.gov** which states:

> The Census Bureau assigns a code and these appear in fields such as
>   “TRACTCE”, where “CE” stands for Census. Finally, state-submitted
>   codes end in “ST”, such as “SLDLST”, and local education agency codes
>   end in “LEA”, as in “ELSDLEA”.

**Which I tried in my code by**:

```
File file = new File("D:\\tl_2018_us_aiannh.shp");

        try {
            Map<String, String> connect = new HashMap();
            connect.put("url", file.toURI().toString());

            DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connect);
            String[] typeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames();
            String typeName = typeNames[0];

            System.out.println("Reading content " + typeName);

            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore
                    .getFeatureSource(typeName);
            SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();
            SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = collection.features();

            try {
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
                    GeometryAttribute sourceGeometry = feature
                            .getDefaultGeometryProperty();
                    String name = (String) (feature).getAttribute("TRACTCE");
                    Property property = feature.getProperty("TRACTCE");
                    System.out.println(property);
                }
            } finally {
                iterator.close();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

But I am receiving null as the value.

Any help would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this. Hope this would be helpful to someone in need.

`SimpleFeature` is the type that has the attributes of shape files that you can check when you try to debug or print a line on runtime. You can use the `SimpleFeature` to get the property. The attributes can be achieved by:

```
  try {
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
         Property intptlat = feature.getProperty("TRACTCE");
     }
 }
```

Make sure you are choosing the *Block Groups* as the layer type for download in `Tiger-Line` or which ever site is concerned, where you download the shape file.